# Is this a case of shadowed variables?

Tags: java, debugging, variables, scope

Totally new to programming. Got a hard-to-debug bug. Was trying to fix it for the 
last couple of days. Got myself to almost hysterical condition by doing that. Decided to sit down and just read the Java book on the random page to calm down. This page was about variable shadowing. Then suddenly I realized I had this nonsense in my code where 
I declare the same variables two times. I removed it and the bug seemed to vaporize.

```
public class Action extends JPanel { 
    private final Color BACKGROUND_COLOR = Color.BLACK; //JPanel background 
    private GameMemory memory = new GameMemory();        
    private int[][] grid = memory.getGrid(); 
    public static Color penColor = Color.GRAY;          //Variable for
                                                        //color

    public Action() { //Setting everything for JPanel
        memory = new GameMemory(); 
        grid = memory.getGrid(); 
        setBackground(BACKGROUND_COLOR); 
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(360, 720)); 
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(360, 720)); 
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension(360, 720)); 
        setVisible(true); 
        new Timer(100, new TimerListener()).start(); 
        //Setting Everything for keylistener
        this.setFocusable(true); 
        this.requestFocus();
        this.addKeyListener(new MyKeyListener());  
    }
```

So what do you guys think? Is this really the shadowing case?

Answer (score 0):

There is no shadowing concept in your declarations.

Shadowing comes into picture ,when  variables having same names with different scopes or Parent and Child have the same variables names and accessing them.

Possibilities are,

Shadowing a local variable **Shadows** An instance variable.

A instnace variable **shadows** the inherited variable from its parent.

```
   grid = memory.getGrid();
```

When you write this, the previous value overridden.

Comment: So in this case and for this particular snippet it does not affect the code in any way? Is just a re-assignment?

Comment: So the variables memory and grid defined on the top are the instance variables who's scope is the class and memory and grid in the constructor are...local to constructor? Does this imply that constructor is a method with its own scope?

Comment: @user3081519 First initialized in class and overridden in constructor. No scope here.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a member variable many ways. You have initialized the variable twice. When it was declared, and in the constructor. There is no need to do it in both places. When you initialize a member variable at declaration, it will be initialized during **every** constructor call. The bug could have something to do with the order the variables  are initialized.